# Run a Ruby's script using Gradle

Tags: android, ruby, build.gradle

I used [Jruby](http://jruby-gradle.org/) in Gradle to run my script, but it gives me this error :

> Error:(16, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'jrubyExec()' Possible
>   causes:
>
> The project 'AppBusiness' may be using a version of
>   Gradle that does not contain the method. Gradle settings
>
> The build file
>   may be missing a Gradle plugin.

this is my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: "com.github.jruby-gradle.base"

import com.**github**.jrubygradle.JRubyExec   --This github is red
task printSomePrettyOutputPlease(type: JRubyExec) {
description "Execute our nice local print-script.rb"
script "print-script.rb"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the answer was the version of gradle was older, after updating the gradle the problem resolved.